# How to show an empty editable view form when no rows are returned?

Tags: 7, views

I am using the [Editable View](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews)s module to create a form that has editable fields from a two custom defined content types linked by a entity ref.

This works fine as long I have at least one row returned by the query.

1) Is it possible to have the form show up empty when the rows returned is zero?

2) Is it possible to have an "editable view" without using the editable table as the format?